# Addition quotations around an R function input?

Tags: r, string, function, quotations

How do I add quotations around an input to a function in R?

I would like to have something such as,

```
function_name (x) { 
paste0("The input you have chosen is", x,)
}

function_name(x = gender)
```

output: "The variable you have chosen is gender"

I know that I could do it using paste0 if the input was
`function_name("gender")`, but I don't know how to do this if the input doesn't have quotations.

I have tried using paste0 to paste single quotations around the word, but gives errors such as:

> Error in paste0("'", x, "'") : object 'Gender' not found.

I have also tried escaping the quotation marks, but the slashes are being read and giving errors as well.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Non-standard evaluation is quite a complex topic. You can read about it and how to use it solve your problem on https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap the parameter with `substitute` function. This enables one to NSE:

```
function_name <- function (x) { 
  paste0("The input you have chosen is ", substitute(x)) #Note here
}
```

And now you can run:

```
function_name(gender) # Without quotes
[1] "The input you have chosen is gender"
function_name("gender") # With quotes
[1] "The input you have chosen is gender"
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by AdroMine, this envolves non-standard evaluation. The link he provided is quite useful.

But to provide an answer, you can do the following:

```
function_name <- function(x) {
  paste("The input you have chosen is", as.character(rlang::enexpr(x)))
}

function_name(x = gender)
[1] "The input you have chosen is gender"
```

We are capturing the "word" `gender` before R tries to evaluate it (i.e., tries to find which value should be associated with `gender`), and then, we are getting the actual text with `as.character()`